# Mongodb $and multiple fields and multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, field

This is my mongo collection structure

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("572d00ca90067001393bfa0f"), "available" : 50, "price" : 5000, "available_date" : ISODate("2016-05-11T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("572d00ca90067001393bfa0f"), "available" : 42, "price" : 5000, "available_date" : ISODate("2016-05-12T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("572d00ca90067001393bfa0f"), "available" : 31, "price" : 5000, "available_date" : ISODate("2016-05-13T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("572d00ca90067001393bfa0f"), "available" : 15, "price" : 5000, "available_date" : ISODate("2016-05-14T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("572d00ca90067001393bfa0f"), "available" : 12, "price" : 5000, "available_date" : ISODate("2016-05-15T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("572d00ca90067001393bfa0f"), "available" : 3, "price" : 5000, "available_date" : ISODate("2016-05-16T00:00:00Z") }
```

I want to search such that 3 dates i.e `2016-05-13` and `2016-05-14` and `2016-05-15` and available field for each of those day is greater than 5.

The `'$and'` condition works on one of them only. How do I get it to work for the 3 dates and available greater than 5?

Comment: Is this your original data or some `$unwind` result?

Answer (score 0):

Query can be as below:-

```
var findQuery = {available_date : {$in : [date:1, date2, date3]}, available : {$gt : 5}};

var cursor = db.collnam.find(findquery);
```

Hope this will help!